# hide vba-code without password request

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a downloaded excel workbook (solve a quadratic equation and draw the curve), and I can't see any vba-code. If opening the VBA-editor (Alt+F11) there is no code to see, but there is also no querying a password for the vba-code.
My question:
How to achieve such a behavior (hide the vba-code without a password request)?

Regards Wicki

Comment: Are you sure that there's no code ? have you checked the worksheet objects if they might contain code ?

Comment: You can't. If you can view the project but can't see any VBA code (did you check all modules including `ThisWorkbook` and the worksheets?) then there isn't any. What format is the file?

Comment: Which is? Feel free to answer your question.

Comment: Now I have found the reason: there is no vba-code and the functionality is reached by using the "formulas" -> "name manager".